# Quitar elementos de un array que ya estan en otro array

Tags: java, java-8, lambda, java-stream

Estimados, 
Tengo un array de alumnos inicial y un array de alumnos nuevos. ¿cómo puedo hacer para obtener un array de alumnos nuevos que no estén en el array de alumnos inicial? Esto usando java lambdas.

**UPDATE**

```
List listaFinal = new ArrayList();

for (Alumno nuevo : listaNuevos) {
    if (!listaRegistrados.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getNombre() == nuevo.getNombre())) {
        listaFinal.add(nuevo);
    }
}
```

funciona pero quisiera saber si hay una forma más simple u ótima. 
Asimismo, quisiera saber si habría algún problema si quisiera usar parallelStream

Comment: Hola Jhon, que has intentado? Por favor agrega el código relevante a tu pregunta

Comment: Ya agregué el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propongo la siguiente solución, la cual es poco costosa a nivel de recursos.

1. Creamos un `Set` con los nombres de alumnos de `listExiste`.
2. Comparamos ese set con la lista de alumnos nuevos, sacando los que no estén contenidos en dicho set.

He hecho la prueba con mi clase `Persona` para no tener que crear una clase `Alumno`. En tu caso, será cuestión de adaptarlo.

Espero te sirva.

```
    /*Datos de prueba*/
    ArrayList<Persona> listExiste = new ArrayList<>();
    listExiste.add(new Persona("Pedro",50));
    listExiste.add(new Persona("Santiago",30));
    listExiste.add(new Persona("Juan",20));

    ArrayList<Persona> listNueva = new ArrayList<>();
    listNueva.add(new Persona("Pedro",50));
    listNueva.add(new Persona("Juan",20));
    listNueva.add(new Persona("Andrés",55));
    listNueva.add(new Persona("Mateo",38));

    /*Obtenemos los nombres de la lista vieja*/
    Set<String> existeNombres = 
        listExiste.stream()
                   .map(Persona::getNombre)
                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    /*Comparamos con la nueva*/
    List<Persona> listResultado =
         listNueva.stream()
                .filter(e -> !existeNombres.contains(e.getNombre()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(listResultado.toString());
```

---

**Output**:

```
debug:
[Andrés: 55 años, Mateo: 38 años]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Genial!! ¿y si quisiera comparar por nombres y apellidos?

Comment: Si quieres comparar por nombre y apellido, lo más simple sería dotar a tu clase de un método que te retorne el nombre y el apellido. Por ejemplo: `public String getNombreCompleto() {
        return nombre+ " "+apellido;
    }`  y cambias la forma de obtener los valores en el `Set`, en vez de esto: `Persona::getNombre` pones esto: **`Persona::getNombreCompleto`** y en la comparación, en vez de esto: `!existeNombres.contains(e.getNombre()`, pones esto: **`!existeNombres.contains(getNombreCompleto()))`**

Answer (score 0):

Con la nueva sintaxis de Streams, es muy fácil escribir código compacto sin darnos cuenta del costo real.

En el caso tuyo, aparte del bucle `for`, hay otro bucle detrás del `anyMatch`. O sea que es un bucle dentro de otro bucle. Si las listas son grandes, se puede llegar a sentir de que no es muy eficiente.

La forma como yo lo haría es de primero convertir `listaRegistrados` a un `HashMap` con el nombre como llave.

Luego puedo iterar la lista `listaNuevos` e ir filtrando de forma eficiente los alumnos verificando el hashmap.

Usando el Streams API, quedaría de esta forma:

```
Map<String, Alumno> registradosMap = listaRegistrados.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Alumno::getNombre, Function.identity()));

List<Alumno> listaFinal = listaNuevos.stream()
        .filter(a -> !registradosMap.containsKey(a.getNombre()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Nota: Estoy asumiendo que tanto `listaRegistrados` como `listaNuevos` son de tipo `List<Alumno>`. Aunque no lo tienes declarado de esa forma en la pregunta, eso sería lo correcto.

Comment: Genial!! ¿y si quisiera comparar por nombres y apellidos?